# DbEntityEntry.State vs DbPropertyEntry.IsModified

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou com uma dúvida sobre essas duas maneiras de especificar se uma entidade foi modificada. Eu geralmente utilizo [`DbEntityEntry.State`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.state(v=vs.113).aspx) com o [`EntityState.Modified`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.entitystate(v=vs.113).aspx) quando faço uma alteração muito grande no *model* e quero que todas elas sejam persistidas no banco de dados, e utilizo o [`DbPropertyEntry.IsModified`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbpropertyentry.ismodified(v=vs.113).aspx) com `true` quando quero especificar que apenas uma propriedade foi modificada.

Então supondo que que eu tenha um *model* e que atualizo várias propriedades dele (mas não todas) durante um processo. Logo em seguida marco o *model* (e não as propriedades modificadas) como `EntityState.Modified` através da propriedade `DbEntityEntry.State`.

Quando eu aplicar as mudanças através do `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` todas as propriedades do model serão atualizadas no banco ou apenas as que foram realmente modificadas? Será gerado um comando UPDATE de SQL que incluirá todos os campos do *model* na atualização?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Quando eu aplicar as mudanças através do `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` todas as propriedades do model serão atualizadas no banco ou apenas as que foram realmente modificadas?

Todas as propriedades são atualizadas, a menos que você especifique quais não serão, assim:

```
var entry = context.Entry(obj);
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
foreach (var nome in new[] { "Prop1", "Prop2", "Prop3" })
{
    entry.Property(nome).IsModified = false;
}
```

> Será gerado um comando `UPDATE` de SQL que incluirá todos os campos do model na atualização?

Se você não especificar quais devem ser excluídos (ou ainda, incluídos), sim. Será com todos os campos.

Se quiser especificar exatamente quais campos serão atualizados, use o seguinte clichê:

```
db.Entidades.Attach(entidade);
db.Entry(entidade).Property(x => x.Prop1).IsModified = true;
db.Entry(entidade).Property(x => x.Prop2).IsModified = true;
db.Entry(entidade).Property(x => x.Prop3).IsModified = true;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Vlw, sanou minha dúvida.